# Keep getting runtime error for simple C program

Tags: c, palindrome

I have to write a program that checks whether the string is a palindrome or not.
A palindrome is a sequence which is the same forwards as backwards.
For example, kayak is a palindrome, canoe is not a palindrome, hannah is a palindrome, etc.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 4096

int main(void) {

    printf("Enter a string: ");

    char line[MAX_CHAR] = {0};

    fgets(line, MAX_CHAR, stdin);

    int length = strlen(line) - 1;

    int i = 0;
    int j = length - 1;

    char line2[length];
    while (i < length){
        if (j >= 0){
            line2[i] = line[j];
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    if (strcmp(line, line2) != 0){
        printf("String is not a palindrome\n");
    } else if (strcmp(line, line2) == 0) {
        printf("String is a palindrome\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works for non-palindromes but each time I test with a palindrome, I am getting a runtime error as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGxQp.png).
How do I solve this?

Comment: You forgot to add a null terminator (`\0`) to `line2` - `strcmp` will go past the end of the array when comparing (and therefore invoke *undefined behavior*)

Comment: @UnholySheep That looks like an answer; you might want to post it in the answer box.

Comment: No it would not work length value is to short

Comment: Your reversal code is wrong... and, you don't need to *reverse* the string to test if a string is a palindrome, just the `strlen()` and a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is caused by the fact that you do not add a null terminator to `line2` (and the array also doesn't have enough space for one), therefore `line2` is not a null-terminated byte string.

Passing a pointer to anything other than a null-terminated byte string to [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) invokes *undefined behavior*

The simplest way to fix your code is to make the following changes:

```
/* Don't subtract 1 from `strlen`, otherwise you don't copy the entire string in your loop */
int length = strlen(line);
/* Unchanged */
int i = 0;
int j = length - 1;
/* increase size of array by 1 to have space for null-terminator */
char line2[length + 1];
/* Loop is unchanged */
while (i < length){
    if (j >= 0){
        line2[i] = line[j];
    }
    i++;
    j--;
}
/* Add null-terminator to have a valid byte string */
line2[length] = '\0';
```

Please also note that there are simpler ways to achieve the palindrome check, but this answer only focuses on why your code runs into the runtime error.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) also stores the newline character inside the array. In order for your palindrome check to work correctly you need to adjust your code (e.g.: removing the newline from `line` before creating `line2` and copying the characters)

Comment: @user3655463 too short for what?

Comment: length has strlen(line)-1 It should be strlen(line) for your solution

Comment: @user3655463 as I noted in the answer I specifically talked about why OP's code "gets a runtime error". But I now added the change to `length` as well

Comment: This will also not work fgets will read new line which will break palindrome check.

Answer (score -1):

Easier way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int palindrome(const char *word)
{
    size_t len = strlen(word);  
    const char *end = word + len -1;
    len >>= 1;
    while(len--)
    {
        if(*word++ != *end--)
            return 1;  //not
    }
    return 0; //yes;
}

int main()
{
printf("%s\n", palindrome("kayak") ? "No" : "Yes");

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have wrong bounds checking, and also fgets reads newline which you have to delete. This is the only compete answer which also check if string entered is not empty:

```
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 4096

int main(void) {

    printf("Enter a string: ");

    char line[MAX_CHAR] = {0};

    fgets(line, MAX_CHAR, stdin);
    //remove new line
    int length = strlen(line);
    if (length > 0) {
        line[length-1] = '\0';
    }

    //update length
    length = strlen(line);
    if (!length) {
        printf("String is empty\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = length - 1;

    char line2[length+1];

    while (i < length){
        line2[i++] = line[j--];
    }

    //Add 0 char
    line2[i] = '\0';
    if (strcmp(line, line2) != 0){
        printf("String is not a palindrome\n");
    } else if (strcmp(line, line2) == 0) {
        printf("String is a palindrome\n");
    }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the down voter but suggesting `scanf()`  instead of `fgets()` is not considerable one. Also `line2` is not null terminated.